# Question on $\xi(\sigma + it)$

Tags: riemann-zeta

I am aware that $\xi(\sigma + it)$ is real for $\sigma = 1/2$. Are there other known values of $\sigma$ for which $\xi(\sigma + it)$  is also real?

Thanks

Comment: why has someone recommended that we close this. Could you please explain. Isn't it a fair question? Thanks

Comment: Any non-constant analytic function has infinitely many curves where it is real... See any complex analysis course

Comment: Is there another value of $\sigma$ in the range $0 < \sigma < 1$ where the function in question is real? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you [try yourself](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+Im(zeta(1%2F4%2BI*t))+from+t+%3D+100+to+200) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\xi(\sigma+it) $ is real for $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}, t=0$.

There are other real values: For the X-rays (lines of pure real or pure imaginary values) of $\xi(s)$ I found https://www.numbertheory.org/pdfs/xrays.pdf. In the picture below you see
the imaginary part of $\xi(x + 10i)$ for $x=-10\dots 10.$

[image]

Comment: I didn't see the $t = 0$ restriction. Anything for non-zero $t$? Thanks

Comment: See the updated answer.